# How we can move a Power App from DEV to PROD using exsisting solution

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

We have developed a solution which contain multiple apps and multiple flow inside our Dev environment. then we imported the solution and export it inside our PROD environment and define the PROD as managed solution.

Now we did some modifications to the Power Apps on Dev and we want to move it to PROD. So what are the steps needed? should we redeploy the whole solution or we can only redeploy the related power apps? and what about the power app id will it differ from the previous version of the app on PROD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redeploy whole solution, follow below steps:

1. Go to solutions menu in DEV
2. Select your solution > select Export Solution option from top menu
3. Publish your changes
4. Export solution as managed solution
5. Go to solutions menu in PROD
6. Import solution > choose **Upgrade** option while importing

Also, Power Apps ID/URL from existing apps in PROD environment will not change.

Check below documentation for more information:

1. [Solutions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview)
2. [Upgrade or update a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/update-solutions)